# Error query jpa spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am working with jpa connect to mysql. when I use query to table database follow:

```html
public interface CommentRepository  extends JpaRepository<Comment1, Integer>{
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM comment1 WHERE contribution_id=:contributionId",nativeQuery = true)
 List<Comment1> findByContributionId(@Param("contributionId") String contributionId);
}
```

```html
package com.example;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

/**
 * Comment1エンティティクラス
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Comment1 implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 /** commentIdプロパティ */
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "comment_id", precision = 11, nullable = false, unique = true)
 public Integer commentId;

 /** contributionIdプロパティ */
 @Column(name = "contribution_id", precision = 20, nullable = false, unique = false)
 public Integer contributionId;

 /** userIdプロパティ */
 @Column(precision = 11, nullable = false, unique = false)
 public Integer userId;

 /** commentプロパティ */
 @Column(length = 2000, nullable = true, unique = false)
 public String comment;

 /** photoIdプロパティ */
 @Column(precision = 11, nullable = true, unique = true)
 public Integer photoId;

 /** stampIdプロパティ */
 @Column(precision = 11, nullable = true, unique = true)
 public Integer stampId;

 /** likeCountプロパティ */
 @Column(precision = 11, nullable = false, unique = false)
 public Integer likeCount;

 /** updateDateプロパティ */
 @Column(nullable = true, unique = false)
 public Timestamp updateDate;

 /** createDateプロパティ */
 @Column(nullable = false, unique = false)
 public Timestamp createDate;

 /** deleteFlgプロパティ */
 @Column(precision = 11, nullable = false, unique = false)
 public Integer deleteFlg;

 // public List<Stamp1> stamp1List;

 /** stampPlaceプロパティ */
 @Column(precision = 11, nullable = false, unique = false)
 public Integer stampPlace;

}
```

My controller transaction

```html
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceComment {
 @Autowired
 CommentRepository commentRepository;
 
 public String findByFb(String contributionId){
  List<Comment1> datas = commentRepository.findByContributionId(contributionId);
  if (datas.size() != 0){
   Comment1 data = datas.get(0);
   return "found " + datas.size()+ "recore";
   
  }else  return "not found recore"; 
  
 }
}
```

My Problem is :
Current my database table "Comment1" exist data with 500 row . with colume "contribution_id" has value from 1 to 2235659. 
- When I query from value contribution_id from 1 to 918 -> query succes
- when I query from 919 to 2235659 it can not find any row though it exist on table.  I think that it relate to config limit query or any problem
Please help me resolve this problem
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
I check more time and find a cause that it relate to colume create_date
If create date > 2015-06-24 15:47:52  it can not query true.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHg3J.png)